# VLC playlist names change to 'playlist' when expanding them

Tags: vlc, playlists

I have created a few playlists in VLC media player. Changed the playlist names by changing the meta data.After quiting and reopening when I take the playlists and expand them,the assigned names change to just 'playlist'.